# Is there an authenticated proxy setting in windows7/10?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy

All outside connections at my work are made through a proxy.

Specifying The IP & port found in Internet Properties->LAN->Proxy Server for a console app I'd like to use yields a "407 proxy authentication required" error.

How do other apps obtain these credentials? For example, why doesn't chrome encounter any error like this without prompting for them?

Does it have something to do with the 'automatically detect settings' option (also in Internet Properties)? If so, how can I view the credentials?

Comment: Where you write "Specifying The IP & port found in Internet Properties->LAN->Proxy Server for a console app I'd like to use yields a "407 proxy authentication required" error." <--- Are you sure you haven't misdiagnosed that.. How do you know it's doing that which yields the error?  What if you don't specify anything there, then what message do you get?

Comment: your last line/ paragraph, speaks of "automatically detect settings' option but doesn't state where you are talking about.. if you mean in chrome then say that in that sentence/paragraph.

Comment: The error is written to stdout. Specifying nothing just times out the connection. I clarified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An authenticated proxy will always issue a 407 on the first attempt to connect through it.  What happens next is largely application dependent.

For Internet Explorer, and other apps that use the system proxy settings (such as Chrome), your Windows credentials are used for authentication, automatically.  This is why the process is transparent.

For apps that manage their own proxy settings, then they need to provide a way to respond to 407 with the credentials.  How this is achieved is entirely down to the application itself.  Some will provide a way to authenticate, and some won't.

If the documentation and support for the application you are using show that it doesn't provide a mechanism for authenticating to the proxy, then you won't be able to.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some way I can determine the type of authentication being used? The app allows for http basic auth. I tried supplying my windows credentials, but I'm still getting 407

Comment: It is unlikely basic auth would be available in a Windows based environment, as NTLM is readily available.  However, when you get the 407, the proxy should also provide a series of `proxy-Authenticate:` headers that describe the options available.  `wget -S` will show the headers, or wireshark.